# Hiding in Plain Sight (not the feat)

Tags: stealth, mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, disguise

I currently have a character who is [a large mass of insects in vaguely human form](http://roninarmy.com/threads/2068?p=87501&viewfull=1#post87501). Due to vagaries of Insubstantial and Growth, he can spread himself out over a large area but, by the book, he'd be just as visible. He doesn't really turn invisible, so Concealment doesn't seem to fit, but what would be the best way to handle "He looks like a bunch of insects spread across the environment"? Would one rank of Morph suffice, with his single form being a slightly higher than normal smattering of bugs around? That would give him a +20 on his Disguise bonus so that, most likely, that's all that people would see. I feel like it might be a case where a slightly higher level of Morph would make more sense, since he could be a variety of different insects depending on context. So he might be the flies on the wall in one context, a cloud of gnats in another, an oddly large number of spiders in a third...

I keep going between morph and just boosting Stealth when he does this. On one hand, the effect kind of models the "no one notices anything is wrong" with the number of bugs around, but on the other hand, he's not exactly hiding *per se* (although, in retrospect, I could probably justify it by claiming that the insects are crawling out of sight), but more that people see the insects, not the recognizable villain.

Comment: Answer in answers, not comments please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also [asked this question](http://roninarmy.com/threads/3111-Hiding-in-Plain-Sight-(not-the-Advantage)) on The Atomic Think Tank, the official forum. The general consensus seems to be purchasing Morph is probably the cleanest way to do it, with most people opining Morph 1 is enough since most people aren't going to know the difference between "this place has more ants than I expect" and "this place has more flies than I expect", but someone familiar with Zzzt's *modus operandi* would be as suspicious about either. Using Stealth, or using Morph, is kind of equivalent since both are opposed by Perception.

My current plans are to put this, the best of both worlds, into my Dynamic array which contains my attacks as "**Multiple Powers: Morph 2 (various groupings of insects), Enhanced Stealth (some amount)**". When using that array slot to look like scattered insects, I have to pay the 10 pp for the Morph effect, and then add as many ranks of Stealth as I feel I have the points for (which can be a lot due to the penalties for Growth) to model the insects hiding from plain view. Trying to disguise myself as part of the background means less offensive capability (fewer points in the array allocated to attacks), but that's an alright tradeoff to me, and that means I can add this power the next time I earn 2 PP for the dynamic slot.

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a good way to do it.